# PHP read content of url with japanese word

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Hi I want to read content of web url having Japanese word in it.

My existing code is as below

```
        $url = "http://fantasticlife稼ぐ777.tokyo" ;

        $responseText = "";
        try {
            $responseText = @file_get_contents($url);
            var_dump($responseText);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

I am getting following output.

```
bool(false)
```

My concern is where the things went wrong. Above code is working fine for normal urls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help? [how to support UTF8 (japanese, arabic, spanish, …) URL's in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907995/how-to-support-utf8-japanese-arabic-spanish-urls-in-php)

Comment: don't include the `http://` because it becomes `http%3A%2F%2F`

Comment: the only other thing that might help is to use a function called `idn_to_ascii` which isn't installed by default by PHP or find a library that is built for this or see if CURL has options for IDN.

Comment: [idna convert](https://phlymail.com/en/downloads/idna-convert.html) and [idn_to_ascii() in 5.2.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405505/idn-to-ascii-in-5-2-17) are some good starting points

Comment: thanks @Class , idn_to_ascii() is working.. I am posting code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks,
Done by converting domain name to IDNA ASCII form. [idn_to_ascii()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php) function. Code snippet is as below.

```
if  (strpos($url,"http://")!== false){
              $url = "http://" . idn_to_ascii(str_replace("http://", "",$url));
        }else if(strpos($url,"https://")!== false){
              $url = "https://" . idn_to_ascii(str_replace("https://", "",$url));
        }else{
             $url = idn_to_ascii($url);
        }
```

Thanks once again. :)