# idn_to_ascii(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries, codeigniter-form-validation

I am using codeigniter framework for my site, but in form_validation I am getting error I followed this link in stackoverflow but it didn't work for me
followed link:
[idn_to_ascii() in 5.2.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405505/idn-to-ascii-in-5-2-17)

Issue:
[image]

code in codeigniter libraries/form_validation.php:

```
public function valid_email($str)
    {
        if (function_exists('idn_to_ascii') && preg_match('#\A([^@]+)@(.+)\z#', $str, $matches))
        {
            $domain = defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46')
                ? idn_to_ascii($matches[2], 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46)
                : idn_to_ascii($matches[2]);

            if ($domain !== FALSE)
            {
                $str = $matches[1].'@'.$domain;
            }
        }

        return (bool) filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    }
```

Comment: what are your CI and PHP versions?

Comment: does this answer help? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255145

Comment: @Vickel codeigniter version 3.1.11

Comment: Please don't post images of text; just paste the text itself into the question. As well as making the question unreadable by anyone with vision impairments or using a limited display, it means that anyone searching for that error message because they have the same problem won't find your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to [upgrade ICU to its latest version](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.3/general/icu.html)

As this was not possible at my shared server, I resolved that problem, extending the CI email library:

- overrules valid_email() function which uses `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46`,  which is unfortunately not installed on my server.
- PhP 7.2 works with that version, so if you have `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003` installed, you get the above deprecated error message.
- SOLUTION: you need to go back to valid_email() function from 2.0 version email library:

  ```
  class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

    public function valid_email($address)
    {
       return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $address)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

  }
  ```

Save this extended Class as MY_email.php in your application/libraries folder. About [Extending Native Libraries](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=extending%20library#extending-native-libraries), the prefix `MY_` is configurable.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is not true that "PHP 7.2 only works with that". It still **works** with `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003`; the message is saying that it is **deprecated**, i.e. support **will be removed in a future version**. It's perfectly safe to ignore that message until you're getting ready to upgrade to the version where it's removed, probably to PHP 8.0, by which time you will probably also be able to update the ICU library

Comment: @Vickel I will check and let u know

Comment: no, just extend the existing one, see the link in the answer about extending Libs

Comment: @Vickel last point I want to ask should I use like this $this->email->valid_email('someval');, if this is not the correct way ell me extact way,I niether used custom libraries or extended libraries

Comment: you only need to extend the library, which you do creating a MY_email.php and place it in the folder I mentioned. That's all. CI will find it automatically and use that new function, whenever needed. You limit yourself using your email library as you would do normally.